# If $E$ is closed and bounded in a metric space $X$ and $f: E → R$ is continous on $E$ , prove that $f$ is bounded on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $E$ is closed and bounded in a metric space $X$ and $f: E → R$ is continous on  $E$ , prove that $f$ is bounded on $E$.

and suppose that $X$ satisfy the Bolzano Weierstrass Property

**attempt:** Suppose $f$ is not bounded on $E$, then there is $x_n \in E$ such that $|f(x_n) | > n$  [equation (1)]

for all natural $n$.

Since $E$ is bounded, we know by the Bolzano Weierstrass Property  that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{k}} → a$ as $k→ \infty$. Since $E$ is closed , then $a \in E$. In particular, $f(a) \in R$. Substite $n_k$ for $n$, in equation 1, and finding limit as $k → \infty$

we have

$|f(x_n)| > n_k$ → $|f(a)| = \infty$.

Thus a contradiction. So $f$ must be bounded in  $E$.

Is this correct? My book has this same proof (Extreme Value Theorem in R), so I am trying to prove it similar to the proof. The only difference is, we are in metric spaces. Can anyone please verify this is fine.
And any suggestion/feedback would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This is false. Not all metric spaces have the Bolzano-Weierstrass property. That's why your book does it on $R$.

Comment: The problem suggest I use the Extreme value theorem as way to prove the above problem in the metric space. It is also given/assume that the metric $X$ satisfies the Bolzano-Weierstrass property.

Answer (score 0):

take $X=(0,1]\cup (2,3)$ and take $E=(0,1]$

Then $E$ is closed in $X$ since its complement is open and take the continuous function $f:(0,1]\rightarrow [1,\infty)$

which is surjective but its image $[1,\infty)$ is not bounded

Comment: Your $X$ does not have the Bolzano-Weierstrass property ("every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence").

Comment: I already mention I can assume the Bolzano Weierstrass property. It is given in the book. Your example seems to contradict the problem